# default key value when reading values from values file in helm chart

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to pass the default key value while reading values file.

```
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.nodeLabel | default map[string]string{"a":"b"}}}
```

**Values.yaml nodeLabel - a: b**

But i am trying to pass default value too.

`{{- range $key, $val := .Values.nodeLabel | default "b:c"`

**error**- `range cannot iterate over b:c`

Comment: So what's the question? Are you having trouble doing what you want? If so, what have you tried? What output do you see, and what did you expect to see instead?

Comment: erro --range cant be iterate over a:b

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 {{- if .Values.nodeLabel -}}
    {{- range $key, $val := .Values.nodeLabel  }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $val }}
  #  {{- end }}
  {{ else }}
     {{ default "b: c" }}
  {{- end -}}
```

Additional resources: [The Chart Best Practices Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/)

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

```
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.nodeLabel | default (dict "a" "b")}}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet. While this code may answer the question, providing [additional context regarding how and/or why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.